# How to draw Trend line with Two Time co-ordinates and Two Price co-ordinates

Tags: pine-script

I am working on a pine script where i have to draw trendline with the help of two time and two price coordinates. Trendline has two points:
first point is the intersection of Price1 with the time1(FromDate)
second point is the intersection of Price2 with the time2(ToDate)

```
//@version=4
study(title="Trend line.new()", overlay=true)

DateFilter = input(true, "------------- Date Range Filtering")
FromYear = input(2020, "From Year", minval = 1900)
FromMonth = input(4, "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
FromDay = input(21, "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
hour1 = input(16, "From-To Hour", minval=1, maxval=24)
min1 = input(15, "From-To Minute", minval=1, maxval=60)


ToYear = input(2020, "To Year", minval = 1900)
ToMonth = input(4, "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
ToDay = input(20, "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
hour2 = input(17, "From-To Hour", minval=1, maxval=24)
min2 = input(15, "From-To Minute", minval=1, maxval=60)


FromDate = timestamp(FromYear, FromMonth, FromDay, hour1, min1)
ToDate = timestamp(ToYear, ToMonth, ToDay, hour2, min2)

price1=281.00
p1=plot(price1, title = "price1", color = #FF0000, transp= 0, offset=0, trackprice = true, linewidth = 1)

price2=276.00
p2=plot(price2, title = "price2", color = #FF0000, transp= 0, offset=0, trackprice = true, linewidth = 1)


line.new(x1=FromDate, y1=price1,x2=ToDate, y2=price2)
```

What changes i have to make in order to work this script....

Comment: You can draw a line using the ``line.new`` function, more info here : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_line{dot}new

Comment: Hello @alexgrover , I am looking for exact solution for this.Will you please give solution with proper we example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
var ln = line.new(x1=FromDate, y1=price1,x2=ToDate, y2=price2, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
```

instead of your last line.

Comment: please have look at my previous question on Pine script error-add to chart operation failed, reason: script has too many local scopes:521. the limit is 500 .I made necessary changes.And looking for a solution..Thanks in advance